# Unable to resolve $proc_date from the script

Tags: shell, hive

I have multiple HQL's, below is the one example.

located at : **/home/ganesh/CopyJobs/hql/**

```
insert into XYZ.exttbl_form_data PARTITION (load_date="$proc_date") select FORM_DATA_ID,FORM_ID,USER_ID,INTERACTIONS_ID,SUBMISSION_DATETIME,FILEDS from PQR.exttbl_form_data where load_date="$proc_date"
```

In the main script im reading above mentioned HQLs as

```
export proc_date=2018-05-07

while read line
do
export hql=`cat /home/ganesh/CopyJobs/hql/$table_name.hql`

export hql_final=$(`eval echo"$hql"`)
echo "Final HQL: $hql_final"
hive -e "$hql_final;"

done < /home/ganesh/CopyJobs/config/tables.txt
```

where in tables.txt has list of all HQL.

I want to resolve the $proc_date however that not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hive variables substitution (hiveconf variables). I have fixed your script a little bit.

1. HQL file should look like this:

   `insert into XYZ.exttbl_form_data PARTITION (load_date='${hiveconf:proc_date}') 
   select FORM_DATA_ID,FORM_ID,USER_ID,INTERACTIONS_ID,SUBMISSION_DATETIME,FILEDS 
   from PQR.exttbl_form_data where load_date='${hiveconf:proc_date}'`

`${hiveconf:proc_date}` - is a variable to be passed to the Hive.

The main script:

```
proc_date=2018-05-07

echo "proc_date is $proc_date"

while read line
do
hql_file=/home/ganesh/CopyJobs/hql/"$line".hql

echo "current hql_file is $hql_file"

hive -hiveconf proc_date="$proc_date" -f "$hql_file"

done < /home/ganesh/CopyJobs/config/tables.txt
```